# NameError: Name is not defined (Only for Test case 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

My code:

```
for i in sys.stdin.readlines():
    lines = i.strip()
for j in range(3): 
    sys.stdout.write(lines + '\n')
```

Test Case 1:

```
Input: "Hello, World!"
Expected Output: 
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```

Test Case 2:

```
Input: ""

Expected Output:
Error: line 6, in
sys.stdout.write(lines + '\n')
NameError: name 'lines' is not defined
```

I am so confused because the first test case working fine but in the second test case "lines" is not defined.
Please help me elaborating on this error and how to fix it, thank you!

Comment: `sys.stdin.readlines()` is empty. That's why `for` loop is not executing hence `lines` is not defined in 2nd Testcase

Comment: yes. It also depends on where the for loop ends

Comment: If you declare lines in one for loop, you cannot access it in another. If you declare it outside of both loops, you can access it in either. Are your for loops nested or separate?

Comment: @ColeHenrich Thank you, I added ```lines = ""``` before those 2 separated for loops and test case 2 works now

Comment: awesome, good luck!

Comment: @Sociopath Thanks, I put ```sys.stdin.readlines(100)``` and also ```lines = '''``` before those 2 for loops and it works now